# Is there a way to detect when a user closes the browser in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have following problem: I need to run code when the user closes his browser. I want my Blazor Server App to Logout the user when he hasn't pressed the Logout button.

CircuitHandlerService.cs

```
  public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler
    {
        
        public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //my code

            return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, 
         cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I have already tried to use Dispose(), OnCircuitClosedAsync() and OnConnectionDown() but none of them actually run the code inside them. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can users be active at the same time in more than one browser? How would you like to handle short internet connection outages (few seconds)?

Comment: My plan was too allow that and to display a warning about conneczion interruption.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to detect when a user closes the browser in Blazor Server?

You need to set up a listener on the browser `beforeunload` event to make a callback into Blazor.

First some JS.

```js
// site.js
// load in _Layout_.cshtml
window.blazr_setExitCheck = function (dotNetHelper, set) {
    if (set) {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", blazr_spaExit);
        blazrDotNetExitHelper = dotNetHelper;
    }
    else {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", blazr_spaExit);
        blazrDotNetExitHelper = null;
    }
}

var blazrDotNetExitHelper;

window.blazr_spaExit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    blazrDotNetExitHelper.invokeMethodAsync("SpaExit");
}
```

A SiteExitService.  Your run whatever code you want in `SpaExit` or register an event handler from elsewhere on `SPAClosed`.

```cs
public class SiteExitService
{
    private IJSRuntime? _js { get; set; }

    private TaskCompletionSource? _taskCompletionSource;

    public event EventHandler? SPAClosed;

    public SiteExitService(IJSRuntime? js)
        => _js = js;

    public async Task SetSpaExit()
    {
        // makes sure we only do it once
        if (_taskCompletionSource is null)
        {
            _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
            var objref = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await _js!.InvokeVoidAsync("blazr_setExitCheck", objref, true);
            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult();
        }

        if (!_taskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
            await _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }


    [JSInvokable]
    public Task SpaExit()
    {
        // do whatever you want to do on exit  Raise an event if you wish
        this.SPAClosed?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Program:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SiteExitService>();
```

Set up in App so it's always loaded.

```cs
// <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
// ...
//</Router>
@code {
    [Inject] private SiteExitService Service { get; set; } = default!;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        => await Service.SetSpaExit();
}
```

Check it works by putting a breakpoint on `this.SPAClosed?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);`.

Comment: I have that in my project now but for some reason I can't debug that. VS will skip the breakpoint. Do I have to enable something?

Comment: I have a solution for each answer.  Here's yours temporarily published on Github so you can hopefully figure out the difference.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO74436633.  I tested this with the breakpoint this morning.

Comment: The breakpoint will be hit now. I also get the warning when I close the page but my code still won't be executed.  It runs perfectly outside SpaExit(). I am calling a method from SpaExit() which is outside of that class which logs the user out.

Comment: To answer that I need to understand what your method is doing.  It's probably trying to act on disposed objects.....  There's two primary processes in disposal mode.  The Renderer tearing down the RenderTree and the Hub tearing down the Hub session and its associated DI container.

Comment: So, my method is connecting to a PostgreSQL server with Npgsql. It then creates a query which removes a session ID at ($1) which equals the username saved in my class Home which I instantiate an object "home" from in SpaExit(). Then it executes the query and closes the connection. I call the method with home.Logout().

Comment: Make sure the code your running is in a singleton service.  It sounds like its async so make sure it's Task based and you await it.  Doing things during teardown is a bit of a minefield.

Comment: What I have done is to add my class Home to a singleton service. Then I am awaiting my logout method in SpaExit() and I have made my method async and return type is Task. I am not sure what I am doing wrong....

Comment: EDIT: After a lot of debugging, I discovered that the user variable used to delete the session ID turns null only in that method. But still couldnt fix it